# Как привести размер данных к одному виду в R?

Tags: r

Помогите пожалуйста в решением.

Есть две таблицы с данными.

Размер строк одной таблицы 30 тыс значений, размер строк второй таблицы 32 тыс значений

При этом данные представляют два временных ряда. Я хотел бы выявить лишние строки и удалить их из общей выборки.

То есть по сути надо сравнивать каждую строчку одной таблицы с другой строчкой такой же таблицы и если обнаруживается, что строчки нет в другой таблице её удалять

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку вы не предоставили образцов данных, решение вслепую:

```
dataset <- rbind(dataset1, dataset2)
dataset <- dataset[duplicated(dataset), ]
```

То есть оставляем только повторяющиеся строки. Можно конкретизировать, по каким столбцам искать дубликаты:

```
duplicated(dataset[, cols])
```

Answer (score 1):

Это звучит как задача для `merge()` или `dplyr::inner_join()`.

---

#### Пример

```
require(dplyr)

one <- data.frame(id = sample(letters,size = 20, replace = F),
                  value = rnorm(20))

two <- data.frame(id = sample(letters,size = 20, replace = F),
                  value = rnorm(20))

joined <- inner_join(one,two,by='id')
```

---

Если нет задачи объединять два дата-сета, а только отфильтровать, можно объединять один датасет с `id` переменной из другого. Например, нужно нам отфильтровать только общие строки в датасете `two`:

```
two_filtered <- inner_join(two, one %>% select(id), by='id')
```

Answer (score 1):

А есть еще лучше решение --  `dplyr::intersect()`

```
library(dplyr)    
joined <- intersect(one, two)
```