# соединение data frame

Tags: r

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как последовательно соединить фреймы с одинаковыми столбцами, но разным количеством строк?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

С помощью функции `rbind` или `data.table::rbindlist`, если важно производительность. См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind

На русском сайте:
[Как привести размер данных к одному виду в R?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503705)